# Jekyll post.content output is surrounded by <p> tag

Tags: jekyll, liquid

When I print the content of the post with

```
{{ post.content }}
```

It is outputted like:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
```

How can I remove the `<p>` tag when generated. I need it to be removed before JavaScript starts to process the DOM.

Comment: I need the same thing, but I cannot go with your answer :(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Jekyll automatically wraps content in `p` tags. You can remove those tags with a liquid command. Per [Jekyll's documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/):

> Because Jekyll grabs the first paragraph you will not need to wrap the
>   excerpt in p tags, which is already done for you. These tags can be
>   removed with the following if you’d prefer:
>
> `{{ post.excerpt | remove: '<p>' | remove: '</p>' }}`

Hope this helps!

Comment: This seems a little verbose if you have lots of output in a template. Any way to disable the `<p>` tag wrapping altogether?

Answer (score 4):

I changed the post file's extension from .md to plain old .html

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could check this answer: [Use a `<div>` to wrap content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20588582/2548155)

I tried and it does work. Probably there's a better way, but I haven't been able to figure it out yet.

Answer (score 2):

To output whole pages without the `<p>` tags, such as to output a .txt or .json file, create a new layout file (e.g. "_layouts/plaintext.html") with this as the entire content:

```
{{ content | remove: "<p>" | remove: "</p>" }}
```

Then call the layout in the header of relevant files, like:

```
---
permalink: sample.json
layout: plaintext
---
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strip_html filter](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/strip_html/). `strip_html` filter is removes any HTML tags from a string.

Example: `{{ post.content | strip_html }}`