# Make Jekyll remove <p> from {{ content }}

Tags: jquery, ruby, datatables, jekyll, liquid

I have a Jekyll site that in the `{{ content }}` has tables in HTML, but just `<tr>` and `<td>`. I'm using [Datatables](http://datatables.net/) since these tables have lots of rows. Since this jQuery plugin asks to have a very clear table, I think the `<p>` Jekyll puts in the middle of the table breaks it. So I would like it to be removed before it's generated.
Is there any way to do it? I'm guessing a jQuery answer could work, but I'd prefer it to be before the DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had this same issue with my site design. I found that when I include code I do *not* want to be in a paragraph tag, all I have to do is put that content into `<div>`s.

Problem solved. Maybe it will work for you?

Comment: It does solve having that `<p>`, but still I've got other problems with Datatables.
Thank you!

Comment: Damn, I hope you figure out the datatable issue. Glad I could help! (:

Comment: This helped me to get inline javascript to work in jekyll templates, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that in order for the dataTables plugin to work, you must use  tags around the header row. Otherwise it won't render.